# Degeneration of modules over the affine symmetric group and jeu de taquin

Tags: hecke-algebras, kazhdan-lusztig, robinson-schensted-knuth

Let $H_n$ be the group algebra of the affine Coxeter group of type A (feel free to replace it by the affine Hecke algebra). This is generated by elements $y_i$'s, $i=1,\dots,n$ and transpositions $s_i$.

These are two commutative subalgebras which can plays the role of a "Cartan subalgebra" to constructs families of modules over $H_n$: the one generated by the $y_i$'s, and the one generated by

$$x_i=y_i+J_i$$

where $J_i$ is the $i$th [Jucys-Murphy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jucys%E2%80%93Murphy_element) element.

As vector spaces we have $H_n=C[S_n]\otimes C[y_1,\dots,y_n]$. So starting with a character $\lambda$ of $C[y_i]$ one can form the induced module

$$M_{\lambda}=C[S_n]\otimes_{C[y_i]} \lambda$$

For $\lambda$ generic enough, $M_{\lambda}$ is irreducible and therefore has to coincides with a certain skew shape representation à la Arun Ram. In particular now the $x_i$'s will have a common eigenbasis labelled by certain generalized skew tableau. Namely for any permutation $\sigma$, there is a unique common eigenvector of the $x_i$ in $M_{\lambda}$ of the form

$$v_{\sigma}=\sigma\otimes 1 + l.o.t. \text{ in the Bruhat order}$$

where of course the coefficients in the lower order terms are rational functions of $\lambda$. Now set $\lambda$ to 0, then of course the above module is not irreducible anymore and factors through the projection $H_n\rightarrow C[S_n]$. It's likely that the above formula for $v_{\sigma}$ thus become singular, but appropriately renormalized it should go to an eigenvector of the JM elements, hence it should be some vector attached to some standard Young tableau in a irreducible submodule of the regular representation of $S_n$ and its spectrum determines this tableau completely.

> **Question**: is there any way to take this sort of limit appropriately, in such a way that $v_{\sigma}$ then goes to a vector labelled by the Robinson-Schensted algorithm applied to $\sigma$ or any kind of Jeu de taquin applied to the generalized skew tableau attached to $v_{\sigma}$ ?

**Why I think it might be true**: If $\mu \subset \lambda$ are two Young daigrams, Arun Ram gives a general construction of irreducible modules attached to a "generalied filling" of the skew shape $\lambda/\mu$. He then shows that as an $S_n$-module, the latter decomposes as
$$\sum_{\nu} c_{\lambda,\mu}^{\nu} S_{\nu}$$

where $S_{\nu}$ is the irreducible $S_n$-module of shape $\nu$ and the $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{\nu}$ are the Littlewood Richardson coefficient. Now recall that the LR coefficient can be defined as the number of standard skew tableau of shape $\lambda/\nu$ whose associated standard tableau via the Jeu de Taquin algorithm is a given fixed tableau of shape $\nu$. Hence the jeu de taquin gives a bijection between the basis of the skew shape module of shape $\lambda/\mu$ and a basis of the same module compatible with its decomposition as a $S_n$-module.

Comment: "...as vector spaces we have..." presumably you meant to take Laurent polynomials in your variables? Or do you really want to work with the affine semigroup (and the degenerate affine Hecke algebra)?

Comment: In the equation defining $M_\lambda$, should we replace $C[S_n]$ by $H_n$? Or $C[y_i]$ by $C$?

Comment: In case $H_n$ is the degenerate affine Hecke algebra, your formula for $x_i$ seems to produce commuting elements (at least, if one chooses the relations between y's and S_n appropriately). But definitely not for $H_n$ the group algebra (or semigroup algebra) of the affine symmetric (semi)group, already for $n=2$: I get $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2+(12)$, which don't commute.